# Как вставить обьект в масив?

Tags: java

Проблема такова: мне нужно вставить в масив обьекты, которые создаются в конструкторе другого класа.
Абстрактный клас

```html
package pack;

public abstract class Instrument {

    String nazwa;
    
    public Instrument() {
        nazwa = "";
    }
    
    public Instrument(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return ("Instrument o nazwie " + nazwa);
    }
    
    public abstract String wydajDzwiek();
    
    public abstract void graj();
}
```

Клас инструментов одного вида

```html
package pack;

public class InstrumentDety extends Instrument {
    
    int lt;
    
    public InstrumentDety() {
        InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
        inst.nazwa = "Zlota Trabka";
    }
    
    public InstrumentDety(String nazwa, int a) {
        
        lt = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
            inst.nazwa = nazwa;
        }
    }

    public String wydajDzwiek() {
        return "Tra ta ta";
    }

    public void graj() {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lt; i++) {
            wydajDzwiek();
            
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Instument dety = " + nazwa + " [lt = " + lt + "]";
    }
}
```

Клас инструментов другого вида

```html
package pack;

public class InstrumentSmyczkowy extends Instrument{
    
int ls;
    
    public InstrumentSmyczkowy() {
        InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
        inst.nazwa = "Stradivarus";
    }
    
    public InstrumentSmyczkowy(String nazwa, int a) {
        
        ls = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
            inst.nazwa = nazwa;
        }
    }

    public String wydajDzwiek() {
        return "Smyk smyk smyk";
    }

    public void graj() {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
            wydajDzwiek();
            
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Instument dety = " + nazwa + " [lt = " + ls + "]";
    }
    
    public boolean jestKontrabasem() {
        
        if (nazwa.equals("kontrabas")) {
            return true;
        }
        
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Мейновый клас

```html
package pack;
import pack.InstrumentDety;
import pack.InstrumentSmyczkowy;

public class Orkiestra {

    static Instrument [] instrument = new Instrument [20];
    int n;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        instrument[0] = new InstrumentDety();
        instrument[1] = new InstrumentDety("rog", 1);
        instrument[2] = new InstrumentDety("puzon", 1);
        instrument[3] = new InstrumentDety("klarnet", 1);
        instrument[4] = new InstrumentDety("tuba", 1);
        
        instrument[5] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy();
        instrument[6] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("altowka", 1);
        instrument[7] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("wiolonczela", 1);
        instrument[8] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("kontrabas", 1);

        
    }

}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я делаю таким способом, у меня возникает такая ошибка:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите бессмысленный код, и ошибки не будет.

```
public InstrumentDety() {
    //InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
    //inst.nazwa = "Zlota Trabka";
}

public InstrumentDety(String nazwa, int a) {
    
    lt = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        //InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
        //inst.nazwa = nazwa;
    }
}

...

public InstrumentSmyczkowy() {
    //InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
    //inst.nazwa = "Stradivarus";
}

public InstrumentSmyczkowy(String nazwa, int a) {
    
    ls = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        //InstrumentDety inst = new InstrumentDety();
        //inst.nazwa = nazwa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я понимаю, да, но задание таково, что в конструкторе ДОЛЖЕН творится обьект, поэтому нужно найти какое-то другое решение

Comment: Объект и так создается после вызова конструктора, а так вы организовываете зацикливание - в конструкторе InstrumentDety создаете новый экземпляр InstrumentDety, то есть снова вызываете конструктор InstrumentDety, который снова создает новый экземпляр InstrumentDety...

Comment: @Andrii "поэтому нужно найти какое-то другое решение" - нe нужно другое решение. Это - решение.

Answer (score 1):

Конструкторы не должны вызывать внутри себя конструкторы других объектов потомков/предков, чтобы избежать рекурсии/зацикливания.

Кроме того, нужно учитывать, что при вызове конструктора класса-потомка будет автоматически вызываться конструктор его класса-предка, и в данном случае нужно вызвать правильный конструктор `Instrument`, чтобы проинициализировалось его название.

Код следует исправить следующим образом:

```java
public abstract class Instrument {

    String nazwa;
    
    public Instrument() {
        this(""); // лучше передать "nie ma nazwy"
    }
    
    public Instrument(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
    }
// ...
}
```

Духовые инструменты, добавили конструктор только с названием

```java
public class InstrumentDety extends Instrument {
    int lt;
    
    public InstrumentDety() {
        this("Zlota Trabka");
    }

    public InstrumentDety(String nazwa) {
        this(nazwa, 1);
    }

    
    public InstrumentDety(String nazwa, int a) {
        super(nazwa); // вызов конструктора предка с параметром
        lt = a;
    }

    public String wydajDzwiek() {
        return "Tra ta ta";
    }

// ...
}
```

Аналогично струнные инструменты:

```java
public class InstrumentSmyczkowy extends Instrument {
    
    int ls;
    
    public InstrumentSmyczkowy() {
        this("Stradivarus");
    }

    public InstrumentSmyczkowy(String nazwa) {
        this(nazwa, 1);
    }

    
    public InstrumentSmyczkowy(String nazwa, int a) {
        super(nazwa); // вызов конструктора предка с параметром
        ls = a;
    }

    public String wydajDzwiek() {
        return "Smyk smyk smyk";
    }
// ...
}
```

Теперь можно будет создавать инструменты для оркестра в классе `Orkiestra`:

```java
instrument[0] = new InstrumentDety();       // Zlota trabka, 1
instrument[1] = new InstrumentDety("rog");
instrument[2] = new InstrumentDety("puzon");
instrument[3] = new InstrumentDety("klarnet", 2);
instrument[4] = new InstrumentDety("tuba");
        
instrument[5] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy();  // Stradivarus, 1
instrument[6] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("altowka", 2);
instrument[7] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("wiolonczela", 2);
instrument[8] = new InstrumentSmyczkowy("kontrabas");
```